# Can you force Vim to show a blank line at the end of a file?

Tags: vim, newline, carriage-return

When I open a text file in Notepad, it shows a blank line if there is a carriage return at the end of the last line containing text. However, in Vim it does not show this blank line. Another thing I've noticed is that the Vim editor adds a carriage return to the last line by default (even though it doesn't show it). I can tell, because if I open a file in Notepad that was created in Vim, it shows a blank line at the end of the file.

Anyway, I can live with these two differences, but I'm wondering if there is an option in Vim that allows you to toggle this behaviour.

Thanks

PS - GVim 7.2

**[Update]**

Would this make sense to be on Server Fault instead?

**[Update 2]**

I'll rephrase this... I need to know when there is a carriage return at the end of single line file (Notepad shows an extra line with no text, with Vim I cannot tell). This is due to a Progress program that reads a text file (expects a single line, but with a carriage return) and parses the text for some purpose. If there is no carriage return, Progress treats the line as if it is null.

**[Workaround Solution]**
One way I've found to ensure there is a carriage return (but make sure I don't add a second one) is to make sure I have the end of line write option turned on (:set eol) and then just do a write/save. This will put an end of line in the file if it's not already there. Otherwise, it doesn't add a new one.

Comment: It wouldn't make any kind of sense on serverfault. Maybe on superuser. But it seems that the consensus is to tolerate vim questions here because vim is considered an IDE.

Comment: Ok thanks... I wonder if SuperUser is out of private beta yet... guess I can go check

Comment: It's still in beta, but not in private, but in semi-private beta: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:help endofline
```

explains how you could stop vim from adding an extra newline.

Comment: Solves one problem... it's the other one (not showing that there is a blank line) that is the bigger issue for me though =\ Has to do with needing to ensure there is a carriage return at the end of a line (and only one).

Comment: I agree I want the line there I just also want to be able to see that it's there.

Answer (score 3):

One useful Vim option is

```
set list
```

It will help you see all end of lines characters (and possibly other generally invisible chars). So you will be able to view this last endofline directly in Vim and not only in Notepad.

Comment: This seems to always show a $ character. Even if there is no blank line afterwards.

Comment: There is no blank line afterwards. vim considers a line something that has a newline at its end. The blank line you are talking about doesn't have a newline, so vim concludes that there is nothing to display.

Comment: See update 2 comments... reworded the question to be more accurate.

Comment: I confirm that even if "diff" prints a difference between those files, using `:set list` those files seem to be identical.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that vim treats newline as a line terminator, while notepad treats it as a line separator:  from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

> There is also some confusion whether
>   newlines terminate or separate lines.
>   If a newline is considered a
>   separator, there will be no newline
>   after the last line of a file. The
>   general convention on most systems is
>   to add a newline even after the last
>   line, i.e., to treat newline as a line
>   terminator. Some programs have
>   problems processing the last line of a
>   file if it isn't newline terminated.
>   Conversely, programs that expect
>   newline to be used as a separator will
>   interpret a final newline as starting
>   a new (empty) line. This can result in
>   a different line count being reported
>   for the file, but is otherwise
>   generally harmless.

If I recall correctly, on unix-y systems a text file must be terminated with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the file in VIM the status line should say `[noeol]` after the filename. So that's one indication. As [Manni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7498/manni) said, you can change this by setting both the `endofline` option off and the `binary` option on. You can set this as your default settings in a `.vimrc` file.