# Vim show newline at the end of file

Tags: vim, newline, eof

Using the `set eol` option Vim automatically adds a newline to the end of the file when it's saved. I have this option on but I would like to be able to see this newline in Vim, so I know that it's actually there.

For example with a file in Vim: [image: Vim screenshot]

And the same file in TextMate: [image: TextMate screenshot]

This always tricks me and I end up adding a second new line and end up realizing later. This exact same question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200856/can-you-force-vim-to-show-a-blank-line-at-the-end-of-a-file) but the answer that was accepted didn't answer this portion of the question.

Using `set list`: [image: List screenshot]

I can see there is a `$` character denoting a new line after the last line but this also litters the rest of the file with these. I know I could set up a toggle for this but I'd really prefer the TextMate like behavior.

Comment: The tidle(`~`) means no new line. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @BillyChan I want to see that there _is_ a new line at the end. Which there is in the screenshots, even though there is a tilde on the same line, so that doesn't make much sense?

Comment: I myself would find seeing `$` very confusing so I would not bother with that:) See if other guys has good answer for you.

Comment: Yea I don't like that either.

Comment: @BillyChan the tilde (`~`) does not mean no new line. If there is a newline at the end of the last line, it would still show a tilde on the next line. (As in the first picture)

Comment: Alternative solution: show `[noeol]` in the statusline https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18238/how-to-show-noeol-flag-in-custom-statusline

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`'endofline'` is on by default so you don't need it in your `~/.vimrc`.

EOL or "newline" doesn't mean "there's an empty line after here", it means "this marks the end of the line, any further characters are to be displayed on another line". "newline" != "new line".

The last line of your file is #21 and it ends with a "newline" character. Since there's no actual line after that "newline" character, no line #22, showing a line #22 is not only wrong but misleading.

TextMate's behavior is wrong.

Vim's behavior is correct.

If you want Vim to show a line #22, you'll need to explicitly add that line but it sounds rather silly to me.

Comment: One thing to note is that this behavior is by every native OS X text editor, not just TextMate

Comment: Could you post your file? I don't see that pesky line here on the two latest version of textmate I just downloaded.

Comment: go to your last line, press enter, save it, open in vim, that line you just created won't be there.

Comment: Though correct, the problem with this behavior is that, a human reader cannot easily finds out whether there is an eol for the last line of the file, except for that `[noeol]` sign in the bottom status line (which is way too hard to notice).  Things get worse with the fact that almost all GUI text editors in Win/Mac adopt the other way: treat newline as line separator rather than line terminator, so that the visual appearance around the end of file directly tells user the existence (or non-existence) of an eol.

Comment: Add the `[noeol]` sign will only be there right after you open the file.  It will disappear once you perform any non-trivial operation.

Comment: TextMate's behavior isn't wrong at all! Every editor in the world shows that empty line which vim doesn't display!

Comment: @KeithSmiley, How did you solve the problem? Why did you accepted this as a solution?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, there's no line to display.

Comment: @romainl, `vim test` > `i` > `enter` > `esc` > `:wq` > `vim test` > line 2 is gone! I manually pressed the enter key with my fingers and typed it, so I expect it to remain there, as I typed it on purpose, yet it disappears! Vim is wrong.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, no, line 2 is not gone.

Comment: @romainl, Are you for real? Before `:wq`, the sidebar shows `1 2`, after it, the sidebar shows `1`. Are you trying to tell me that these are equal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128153/discussion-between-iulian-onofrei-and-romainl).

Comment: Let aside what is wrong and what is correct.


Is there a way to configure vim to show that final line? I mean to configure it to work "incorrectly" as most of Win/Mac editors do?

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat, again, **there's no line to show**.

Comment: I said "Let aside what is wrong and what is correct".

Comment: And I said "there's no line to show". Vim can't be configured to show a line that doesn't exist.

Comment: Please reread the comment of neverhoodboy above. It explains a lot. More info on wikipedia.

Comment: I already read it two years ago and I have written [another longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224292/546861) to a similar question two years before. There is no line to display and no way to force Vim to display a line that's not here, no matter if you are comfortable with that behavior or not.

Comment: `Ga` is "jump to last line and append after the cursor" so there's no reason whatsoever to use that command to "jump to last line and add a new line". You would use `Go` for that.

Comment: Not only is not "wrong" to treat a newline as a separator, there is no newline character. There's a linefeed character, which tells a line printer to move the paper forward, and a carriage return character. How those get repurposed in ASCII files is a matter of convention, and varies with operating system and software. (Which also means that whether the newline character implies the existence of a blank line after it is, again, down to what you're using.) Vim's default happens to be most convenient for writing version-controlled code.

Comment: Downvoting: not only does this not answer the question, but it's also factually incorrect."TextMate's behavior is wrong.
Vim's behavior is correct." Really? Are you the world authority on text editors? Actually none of them is wrong. `\n` can be seen either as line terminator or line separator, and Textmate and VIM view it differently. I argue that actually TextMate's (and MANY other text editors) is more useful, because it makes it very obvious when the file ends with a newline. VIM's behavior is super irritating - I ended by mistake many files with 2 newlines.

Comment: Another factual error: _"Since there's no actual line after that "newline" character, no line #22, showing a line #22 is not only wrong but misleading."_ There is actually a line after the last newline - a line that has zero characters. Again, it's not wrong, it's a different way of looking at things, and the current VIM behavior is super unuseful - it basically shows no difference between a file that ends with a newline and one that doesn't (if you don't configure it to display newline characters).