# Have VIM add a final new line on save

Tags: linux, unix, vim, text, gnu

I would like VIM to add a final new line when I save my text files. Oddly, searching for it I only find instructions on how to disable this behavior, however I explicitly want it.

This is my VIM installation:

```
$ vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 18 2016 01:00:23)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1525
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         -gettext         -mzscheme        +title
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   -toolbar
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        +user_commands
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +visual
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visualextra
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +viminfo
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +vreplace
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +wildignore
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildmenu
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +windows
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +writebackup
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       -X11
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -xfontset
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xim
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xsmp
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_save
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xpm
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

My .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc source %

set nocompatible
filetype off

" Set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

syntax on
colorscheme solarized

set backspace=2
set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1
set laststatus=2
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set number
set hidden
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set mouse=a

" Use ag over grep
set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

" Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'

" ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0

for dir in ['backup', 'swap', 'undo']
    let path = $HOME . '/.vim/' . dir
    if !isdirectory(path)
        call mkdir(path, 'p')
    endif
endfor

set backupdir=~/.vim/backup//
set directory=~/.vim/swap//
set undodir=~/.vim/undo//

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

let mapleader=","
imap jj <Esc>
nnoremap ; :

" Yank text to the OS X clipboard
noremap <leader>y "*y
noremap <leader>yy "*Y

" Preserve indentation while pasting text from the OS X clipboard
noremap <leader>p :set paste<CR>:put  *<CR>:set nopaste<CR>

" Disable arrow keys
map <up> <nop>
map <down> <nop>
map <left> <nop>
map <right> <nop>

" Easy window navigation
map <C-h> <C-w>h
map <C-j> <C-w>j
map <C-k> <C-w>k
map <C-l> <C-w>l

" Clear search
nmap <silent> ,/ :nohlsearch<CR>
```

Comment: That's probably the `binary` option. If set, vim won't add a newline in the last line. Vim may set the `binary` option automatically based on the recognized filetype. You can test with `:set binary?`.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly `nobinary`

Comment: Do you want to add an actual empty line after the last line or do you want to add a "newline" character at the end of the last line? The former makes no sense but it could probably be done with an autocommand. Vim already does the latter by default.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful! VIM is indeed writing the newline character, which I want, it is just not displaying it as I am used from other editors. Opening it in a different editor I can actually see the last blank line, which VIM seems to hide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222530/why-do-i-need-vim-in-binary-mode-for-noeol-to-work/16224292#16224292

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) figured out, VIM was indeed inserting the EOL character, however unlike other editors I am used to, it is not displaying it as a new line.

See: [Why do I need vim in binary mode for 'noeol' to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222530/why-do-i-need-vim-in-binary-mode-for-noeol-to-work/16224292#16224292)