# Vim don't show last empty line

Tags: linux, vim

I have written some c code, and the end of my output is '\n', when I check the output text file in vim, I cannot find the last empty line, however, when I open it with another text viewer, I can find the last empty line. How can I configure my vim to show the empty line?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Vim shows `\n` / 0x0a at the end of the file is that it opens the file without complaining about `[noeol]` when `:edit`ing the file (in a kind of "reverse logic" from what you expect). Vim's (and Unix) philosophy is that the trailing newline *should be there*. This can be confusing when one is used to other editors or predominantly works on MS Windows.

There's a lot of discussion and questions about this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222530/why-do-i-need-vim-in-binary-mode-for-noeol-to-work)); as this is unlikely to change, get used to it.