# how to tell when vim has added EOL character

Tags: vim, newline, eol

How I can see in vim when a file has a newline character at the end?  It seems vim always shows one, whether it's truly there or not.

For example, opening a file that has a newline at the end:

```
echo "hi" > hi
# confirm that there are 3 characters, because of the extra newline added by echo
wc -c hi 
# open in binary mode to prevent vim from adding its own newline
vim -b hi
:set list
```

This shows:

```
hi$
```

Now by comparison, a file without the newline:

```
# prevent echo from adding newline
echo -n "hi" > hi
# confirm that there are only 2 characters now
wc -c hi 
# open in binary mode to prevent vim from adding its own newline
vim -b hi
:set list
```

Still shows:

```
hi$
```

So how can I see whether a file truly has a newline at the end or not in vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim show newline at the end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639511/vim-show-newline-at-the-end-of-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim stores this information in the `'endofline'` buffer option. You can check with

```
:setlocal eol?
```

Comment: very confusing that it's called "eol" instead of "eof".  Overall a disappointing behavior from vim, but so it is

Comment: Well, the missing character is an end-of-line / newline character. Think of it only applying to the last line in a buffer. What you find disappointing is just good style in the Unix mindset. The vi heritage shows here, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, Vim displays `[noeol]` when loading the file.

Don't you see the `[noeol]` output, when loading that file?

Answer (score 1):

Vim warns you when it opens/writes a file with no `<EOL>` at the end of the last line:

```
"filename" [noeol] 4L, 38C
"filename" [noeol] 6L, 67C written
```